# Oracle SQL listagg multiple column in one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this following db with query and result [image](https://prnt.sc/iyq1en)
but as you can see there are mutiple times returned the same name it should look like Rob, Rose, Will and thats it. What should i do to reach this goal? Is there anything wrong in my query?

```
SELECT FILM.NAZEV, FILM.VYDANI, FILM.DELKA, FILM.CENA, LISTAGG(OSOBA.JMENO, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OSOBA.JMENO) AS ProdukceFROM FILM_PRODEJNA
INNER JOIN FILM ON FILM_PRODEJNA.FILM_ID_FILM = FILM.ID_FILM
LEFT JOIN FILM_PRODUKCE ON FILM_PRODUKCE.FILM_ID_FILM = FILM.ID_FILM
LEFT JOIN PRODUKCE ON PRODUKCE.ID_PRODUKCE = FILM_PRODUKCE.ID_FILM_PRODUKCE
LEFT JOIN ZASTOUPENI ON ZASTOUPENI.ID_ZASTOUPENI = PRODUKCE.ID_PRODUKCE
LEFT JOIN OSOBA ON ZASTOUPENI.OSOBA_ID_OSOBA = OSOBA.ID_OSOBA GROUP BY FILM.NAZEV, FILM.VYDANI, FILM.DELKA, FILM.CENA;
```

Comment: Please post the text of your code

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing your input data. Run the query without the GROUP BY clause and without the LISTAGG, and try to figure out why you get triplicates in the multi-join for one of the films. You need to fix THAT issue - then the LISTAGG will produce the correct result without any other work.

Comment: [without](https://prnt.sc/iyqcaa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty is that you have duplicate names returned by your query. And sadly you can't use `DISTINCT` with `LISTAGG()`. So you have to do something like the following:

```
SELECT nazev, vydani, delka, cena
     , LISTAGG(jmeno, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY jmeno) AS Produkce
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT FILM.NAZEV, FILM.VYDANI, FILM.DELKA, FILM.CENA, OSOBA.JMENO
      FROM FILM_PRODEJNA INNER JOIN FILM
        ON FILM_PRODEJNA.FILM_ID_FILM = FILM.ID_FILM
      LEFT JOIN FILM_PRODUKCE ON FILM_PRODUKCE.FILM_ID_FILM = FILM.ID_FILM
      LEFT JOIN PRODUKCE ON PRODUKCE.ID_PRODUKCE = FILM_PRODUKCE.ID_FILM_PRODUKCE
      LEFT JOIN ZASTOUPENI ON ZASTOUPENI.ID_ZASTOUPENI = PRODUKCE.ID_PRODUKCE
      LEFT JOIN OSOBA ON ZASTOUPENI.OSOBA_ID_OSOBA = OSOBA.ID_OSOBA
) GROUP BY nazev, vydani, delka, cena;
```

Basically, I took your query, added `DISTINCT`, and used it as a subquery for `LISTAGG()` etc. But I think the inclusion of this table `FILM_PRODEJNA` is your real problem. There are multiple prodejny (I hope I have that right) per film, right? But you only want to find films with at least one prodejna? In that case I would recommend using `EXISTS` instead of an `INNER JOIN`. Of course there might still be duplicates, I don't know the exact relationships between your tables:

```
SELECT FILM.NAZEV, FILM.VYDANI, FILM.DELKA, FILM.CENA
     , LISTAGG(OSOBA.JMENO, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY OSOBA.JMENO )
  FROM FILM
  LEFT JOIN FILM_PRODUKCE
    ON FILM_PRODUKCE.FILM_ID_FILM = FILM.ID_FILM
  LEFT JOIN PRODUKCE
    ON PRODUKCE.ID_PRODUKCE = FILM_PRODUKCE.ID_FILM_PRODUKCE
  LEFT JOIN ZASTOUPENI
    ON ZASTOUPENI.ID_ZASTOUPENI = PRODUKCE.ID_PRODUKCE
  LEFT JOIN OSOBA
    ON ZASTOUPENI.OSOBA_ID_OSOBA = OSOBA.ID_OSOBA
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM FILM_PRODEJNA
                 WHERE FILM_PRODEJNA.FILM_ID_FILM = FILM.ID_FILM )
 GROUP BY FILM.NAZEV, FILM.VYDANI, FILM.DELKA, FILM.CENA;
```

If I could make a comment, you'll save yourself some typing if you use table aliases - that way you needn't type `ZASTOUPENI` over and over again, for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple records that causes duplicates in the listagg function. The best way to fix it is to find the data that is causing the duplicate. BUT if you want to take a shorter way of fixing it and sacrifice efficiency, you may do a sub-query and select distinct on all columns that you need then do the listagg group by.  See below.

```
SELECT FILM.NAZEV, 
   FILM.VYDANI, 
   FILM.DELKA, 
   FILM.CENA, 
   LISTAGG(film.JMENO, ',') 
      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY film.JMENO) 
AS Produkce
    FROM (select distinct FILM.NAZEV, 
       FILM.VYDANI, 
       FILM.DELKA, 
       FILM.CENA,
       OSOBA.JMENO
 From  FILM_PRODEJNA
INNER JOIN FILM ON FILM_PRODEJNA.FILM_ID_FILM = FILM.ID_FILM
LEFT JOIN FILM_PRODUKCE ON FILM_PRODUKCE.FILM_ID_FILM = FILM.ID_FILM
LEFT JOIN PRODUKCE ON PRODUKCE.ID_PRODUKCE = FILM_PRODUKCE.ID_FILM_PRODUKCE
LEFT JOIN ZASTOUPENI ON ZASTOUPENI.ID_ZASTOUPENI = PRODUKCE.ID_PRODUKCE
LEFT JOIN OSOBA ON ZASTOUPENI.OSOBA_ID_OSOBA = OSOBA.ID_OSOBA ) FILM
GROUP BY FILM.NAZEV, 
   FILM.VYDANI, 
   FILM.DELKA, 
   FILM.CENA
```

Comment: The problem with allowing the duplicates to survive, and just working around that, is that perhaps in the future someone will want to add a COUNT column, or a TOTAL REVENUE (CENA means price, I believe). At that time, they may not realize that they are duplicating data, and that the counts, and the revenue, are three times the correct values. The only correct action at this time, IMO, is to figure out what causes duplicates in the first place, and to correct the issue.